# Choose different size image to download when in different internet connection

Tags: android, ios, image, web, networking

Our app is serving different users with different internet connection, some are very poor slow internet, some are fast internet connection.

We would like to download and display different size image accordingly.

For those poor internet users: download and display https://example.com/some-image.jpg?type=small
For those good internet users: download and display https://example.com/some-image.jpg?type=normal

How can we do this? any solution to do this? We have Android and iOS app.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm searching google, and have no idea what to do..

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link if you are using glide to load the images
[Network-Dependent Image Loading - Using Glide](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-network-dependent-image-loading)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're going to have to have your device determine the network speed anyway, why not just make it a query parameter of the image and download the correct url according to your speed?  This will work on any platform that can detect download speed.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Do you mean I do something like GET http://example.com/test-network-speed?download=a.jpg ?

So I have to provide an interface `test-network-speed` that can test speed and return the image specified in the parameter?

But is this interface able to determine speed in server side? I thought the speed must be done in app side..